# Exception format for parsers written in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, exception

I'm writing parsers in Node.js for some file formats. When a parser detects an error, an exception will be thrown. For the exact format of the exception, I figure it would be best if I go with something that's already a de facto standard. So I looked at Acorn and Esprima to see what kind of exceptions they throw... and they disagree on format.

So what is the closest thing to a standard/preferred parser exception format?

Answer (score 0):

The closet thing to a true standard that I know of, assuming your parser runs in a shell, is to return a non-zero exit code from your process if the parsing was unsuccessful.  Other than that, not sure how there could be too much of a standard outside of some uber-parsing protocol, because different file formats can have very different semantics and syntax and so very different semantic or syntax errors.

Comment: I'm talking about API, programmatic use, exceptions, not running as a standalone program which is a different matter. And sure there can. The error needs to note line and column number. There's no reason why people shouldn't be able to agree on the names of the fields storing these things.